# Checked checkbox returning the value "on"

Tags: php

I have the following checkbox

`<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="status" '.$activeCheck.'/>`

and setting a value whether its checked or not here.

`$new_status = (isset($_POST['status'])) ? 'active' : NULL;`

However when i submit to the database using the `$new_status` variable it is "on" when it should be "active"

Insert Query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO exhibitions (code, name, description, notes,
                                    status, image, slug, start_date, end_date)
      VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
      $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
      $stmt->bind_param('sssssssss', $code, $new_name, $new_description, $new_notes, $new_status, $new_image, $new_slug, $new_startDate, $new_endDate);
```

Comment: Can you include more of the code, especially where you insert the data.

Comment: `on` is the default value of a checkbox. You can give it a `value` attribute to overwrite it. That said, you are probably overwriting the `$new_status` variable somewhere if you get `on` back.

Comment: It must be that somewhere in your code you have a typo. Instead of using `$new_status` you use `$_POST['status']`

Comment: @Dharman I'm afraid not :(

Comment: Can you dump the $_POST['status'] obj? Or maybe you are somewhere in your code resetting $new_status?